# Translating PostGIS query to Django QuerySet (GeoDjango)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I am trying to figure out how to translate a PostGIS query to GeoDjango that uses two different tables, this is an example of a query I need to do.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM county a, cd b
WHERE a.state = 'Virginia'
AND b.state = 'Virginia'
AND b.cd114fp = '06'
AND ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom)
```

This is the docs for geodjango queries. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/

however, it doesn't go over how to do a more complicated query like the one above, and I'm not too familiar with django queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geo = serialize('geojson', County.objects.filter(
        state="Virginia"
        geom__intersects=Cd.objects.filter(state="Virginia", name="06")
      ))
```

I figured it out, it was pretty simply just had to familiarize myself with django queryset some more.